# Como faço para setar como null a data do Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

Quando envio os dados para validação consta que o campo possui uma data preenchida, como a data de hoje. Gostaria de setar como null a principio obrigando o usuário a preencher o campo.

DATEPICKER

```
   $('#datepicker')
        .datepicker({
         format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
         language: "pt-BR",
         orientation: "top auto",

    });
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         if ($( "#tipo_retorno" ).val() == "AGENDAMENTO"){

                $("div.atendimento-simples").hide();
                $("div.atendimento-agendamento").show();
            }
   });

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tipo_retorno').on('change', function(){
    var demovalue = $(this).val();

    if(demovalue == "AGENDAMENTO") {

       $("div.atendimento-simples").hide();
        $("div.atendimento-agendamento").show();

            }else{
        $("div.atendimento-simples").show();
        $("div.atendimento-agendamento").hide();
    }


});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar o defaultDate

```
$('#datepicker')
        .datepicker({
         format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
         language: "pt-BR",
         orientation: "top auto",
         defaultDate: '00/00/0000'
    });
```